# PHP Mail Not Sending But No Errors

Tags: php, email

So I've got a script which sends email, it works on one domain on my VPS but not on another which is very confusing! I've checked all the smtp details...etc. and can't see any reason for it. The script runs as though it is successful and throws up no errors and the variables are all in place.

If anyone has any ideas would be hugely appreciated!

```
<?php
$email=$_POST['email'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$business=$_POST['business'];
$town=$_POST['town'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$rpo=str_replace("rpo", "RPO",$_POST['rpo']);
$retained=str_replace("retained", "Retained",$_POST['retained']);
$ats=str_replace("ats", "ATS",$_POST['ats']);

$interest=$rpo . ' ' . $retained . ' ' . $ats;
$interest=str_replace('','<br>',$interest);

$msg = "You've received a new enquiry from $name at $business<br>
They are based in $town and interested in:<br>
$interest<br>
You can contact them on:<br>
<b>Phone: </b>$phone<br>
<b>Email: </b>$email<br>
This is an automatically generated email from the company website generated from http://example.com";

$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

mail('example@example.com','New Enquiry',$msg);

header("location:http://example.com");
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#121163 ?

Comment: try with `if(mail('example@example.com','New Enquiry',$msg))` to make sure the mail function working

Comment: Done that and it comes up with a blank page i.e. no errors

Comment: I mean by `if(mail('example@example.com','New Enquiry',$msg)){echo "sent";}else{
echo "failed"; }`

Comment: Sorry I was responding to first comment and din't see yours! I'll try that now

Comment: Yep it echoes as sent but nothing has been received

Comment: check your mail logs, and if `sendmail` is not installed then install that by if ubunut `apt get install sendmail` then config sendmail

Comment: have you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this to find out where is the problem

```
$success = mail('example@example.com','New Enquiry',$msg);
if (!$success) {
   print_r(error_get_last()['message']);
}
```

with a glance at [Php Mail Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> Note:
>   When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.
>   Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.
>
> ## Return Values
>
> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

**update**
After comments just for test, remove every code in your php file an just try the simplest way to debug

```
<?php
// the message
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
if(!mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg)){
    var_dump(error_get_last()['message']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done this and it comes up with no error messages at all and everything acts as though it is sent

Comment: Hmm what's even stranger is I don't get TRUE or FALSE it is just blank

Comment: Ah that's why it says $success is undefined

Comment: @Rockhopper have you check it with `$success !==true`?. yes seems strange.

Comment: @Rockhopper check my code again.

Comment: Still coming up as blank, I am so confused! lol

Comment: @Rockhopper check my code again, ( have print_r the error?) ?

Comment: Thank you so much for all this, out and about now and will test when I'm back online

Comment: @Rockhopper you're welcome, inform me about the result.